# How to create dictionary combinations? Costliest car problem

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to create combinations from 2 dictionaries list.

From trims, choose 1 item.

From extras choose from 1 to 4 items; but they can't be repeated.

```
def costliestCar(maxPrice):
    basePrice = 159000

    trims = {'A': 0, 'B': 22000, 'C': 40000}
    extras = {'cruise': 4000, 'air': 7000, 'alloy': 8000, 'chrome': 13000}   

return carSpecification
```

Consider a maximum price of 170500. Subtracting the base price, there is 11500 left to spend. The most expensive car combination within the budget is the trim level A with the extra options cruise and chrome, so the output of the function must be:

```
A, cruise, chrome
```

The total price of the car is thus 159000 + 0 + 4000 + 7000 = 170000, which does not exceed the budget of 170500.

```
costliestCar(maxPrice=170500)
    output: A, cruise, chrome
```

I was thinking something like; but then I'm stuck:

```
carlist = []
for trim in trims:
    car = (basePrice, trim)
    carlist.append(car)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could break down what kind of combinations you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I do not understand how you get to your numbers. 170500 is not possible even if one takes the sum of all..

Comment: This is pretty interesting, because you cannot simply do 2 for loops, you must loop through the extras adding them in combination. I think the real question here is how can you go through the extras dict and find the cost of each added together, for all 4! possible combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a generator to get all of the combinations of extras

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def all_combinations(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        yield from combinations(seq, i)
```

Then we can use product to get every trim and every combination of extras

```
product(trims.items(), all_combinations(extras.items()))
```

That gives us `((trim, price), ((extra, price), ...))` tuples.  We want to get `((trim, (extra, ...)), price)` tuples, so we can write a function

```
def sum_prices(t):
    (trim, price), extras_t = t
    if extras_t:
        extras, prices = zip(*extras_t)
    else:
        extras, prices = (), ()
    price += sum(prices)
    return ((trim, extras), price)
```

Then we can get the maximum price below our threshold

```
threshold = 170500- 159000

prices = map(sum_prices, product(trims.items(), all_combinations(extras.items())))
prices = ((options, price) for options, price in prices if price <= threshold)
best = max(prices, key=lambda t: t[1])
# (('A', ('cruise', 'air')), 11000)
```